# Wordpress - update_post_meta from current dropdown value on button click?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

On my single-product.php page, I have a dropdown select. There's also a button on the page to save the post to your favorites. Is there a way I can update the post's meta information with the currently selected value from the dropdown when the favorite button is clicked with something like below?

```
update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'newcolor', $value );
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course. You will need to use AJAX here, which will allow you to run a PHP script without refreshing this page.

First, you need to create a new PHP script, called **add_favorite.php** which will contain :

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
update_post_meta($id, 'newcolor', $value);
```

Then you can use the $.ajax() function from jQuery to call this script asynchronously and update the post meta in the database. On return, you will be able to change with javascript a specific element of your HTML to reflect the change (added to favorites).

```
request = $.ajax({
    url: "add_favorite.php",
    type: "post",
    data: // send the id here
});

// Callback handler that will be called on success
request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
    console.log("Hooray, added to favorites!");
});
```

See this answer to learn how to send AJAX data : 
[jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

This is from jQuery API documentation. Data can be of type string or Array. Use array if multiple values ['id'=> $id] :

```
data
Type: PlainObject or String or Array
Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if  not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/